# Docker Container Attached to Network, Network Inspect Shows No Containers

Tags: linux, docker, ubuntu, networking, ros2

I am simply trying to **connect a ROS2 node** from my Ubuntu 22.04 VM on my laptop **to another ROS2 node on another machine** running Ubuntu 18.04. Ideally, I would only have Docker on the second machine (the first machine runs a trivial node that will never change), but I have been trying using a separate container on each.

**Here is what I am doing and what I am seeing when I inspect:**

(ssh into machine 2 from VM 1.)

[A: start up network from machine 2.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ST0M5.png)

```
sudo docker network create -d overlay --attachable my-attachable-ovrlay
```

[B: start up container 1.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HxFCV.png)

```
sudo docker run -it --rm test1
```

[C: successfully attach container 1 to the network.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/En2fq.png)

```
sudo docker network connect dwgyau64pvpenxoj2edu4liqu bold_murdock
```

[D: Confirm the container lists network.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TWtJY.png)

```
sudo docker inspect -f '{{range $key, $value := .NetworkSettings.Networks}}{{$key}} {{end}}' bold_murdock
```

prints:

```
bridge my-attachable-ovrlay
```

[E: Check the network to see container.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lsdfO.png)

```
sudo docker network inspect my-attachable-ovrlay
```

prints (among other things):

```
"Containers": null,
```

I am new to Docker AND networking, so I could be missing something huge, but **I have tried all of the standard suggestions** I found online including **disabling my firewall**, opening a ton of ports using **ufw allow** on both machines, making sure **nodes are active**, etc etc etc etc etc.

I tried joining the network from machine 2 and that works and the container is displayed when using network inspect. But when I do that, then machine 1 simply refuses to connect to network.
[F: In this situation it gives an error.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5riY3.png)

```
sudo docker network connect dwgyau64pvpenxoj2edu4liqu objective_mendel
```

prints:

```
Error response from daemon: attaching to network failed, make sure your network options are correct and check manager logs: context deadline exceeded
```

Also, **before trying any docker networking, I have tried plainly pinging from VM1 to machine 2 and that works, both ways.** I have tried to use netcat to open an old-timey chat window on port 1234 (random port as per [this resource](http://wiki.ros.org/ROS/NetworkSetup)) and that works one way only. I can communicate both ways, but only when machine 1 sends the initial netcat request and machine 2 listens. When machine 2 sends request and 1 listens, nothing happens.

I have been struggling to get this to work for 3 weeks now. I know it’s something stupid, I just know it. Any advice would be incredibly appreciated. Please explain like I know *nothing* about networking, because I just about do.

EDIT: I converted images (still hyperlinked) into code blocks.

Comment: Please read: [Why not upload images of code/errors when asking a question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question)

Comment: Ok. Next time I will do that. But I still need help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was that the router was set to 1969. When we updated the time by connecting to the internet for 15 seconds, then disconnected, it started working.

Answer (score 0):

If both PCs are on the same LAN, you could skip the whole network configuration entirely and use ROS2 auto-discovery.

E.g.

PC1:

```
docker run -it --rm --net=host -v /dev/shm:/dev/shm osrf/ros:foxy-desktop
    export ROS_DOMAIN_ID=1
    ros2 run demo_nodes_py talker
```

PC2:

```
docker run -it --rm --net=host -v /dev/shm:/dev/shm osrf/ros:foxy-desktop
    export ROS_DOMAIN_ID=1
    ros2 run demo_nodes_py listener
```

If the PCs are not on the same network, I usually use [ZeroTier](https://www.zerotier.com/) to create a virtual LAN between PC1, PC2, and PC(N), then repeat the above example.

Comment: Thank you very much for your suggestion. I tried exactly what you put, but PC2 is a Jetson Nano, so osrf/ros:foxy-desktop doesn't work. I ran a different ros2 image, but the exact same on both machines. Unfortunately, this does not work. I do not see the topic being published.

Comment: I did take down my firewall and I even tried running two docker containers on the jetson, and they were able to communicate using the talker and listener. I confirmed PC1 was on my network, and ran the same exact container on PC1 as was on PC2. The topic /chatter was not listed.

Comment: I've had similar issues on a university network such as 'Eduroam', where the firewall from the ISP/It-department is blocking certain communication.

Comment: Check that you are using the same DDS vendor on both machines and that you are bridging the network from VM to host PC.

Comment: I am using a private router, which is not connected to the internet. It should not be blocking any communication, but idk anything about networking. I'm not sure how to do what you said, but I will do my best to figure it out tomorrow and keep you updated. Thanks again for helping

Comment: Are you using the same DDS vendor on both machines "export RMW_IMPLEMENTATION=..."? Just to be sure. Make sure that that the VM has bridged network to host pc. I.e.  configure the network on the VM (guest) as bridged, meaning that the VM will use your physical network card (host) and it will get its own IP from the router. If you are running any docker with ROS2 on a MacBook, there is very little luck getting that communication out due to not having the docker0 on hosting MacBook.

Comment: I can't seem to figure out how to display the DDS vendor. I am also not on a Macbook, I am on Windows running Ubuntu 22.04 VM. HOWEVER, my VMWare VM Network Adapter was set to NAT, "Used to share host IP address" and NOT bridged! I changed to bridge and now the router settings SHOWS TWO IP ADDRESSES wirelessly connected. Two mac addresses as well. One is labeled "XXX-virtual-machine" Unfortunately, I still do not see the talker from either side. Also, I can no longer open the old-fashioned chat window using netcat. I also tried checking and unchecking "replicate physical network state"

Comment: I would try to identify which PC is blocking the communication to the network by removing potential faults until it's working and then build up from there.

E.g. borrow a raspberry pi / laptop with ros2 installed on and try to get that device to communicate with either PC.

Comment: Sorry, it has been a very busy week. I did as you suggested and borrowed a friend's pure Linux machine (I mean not a VM). We were able to get ros2 working in two separate docker containers both on his machine, but not to my VM (PC1) OR the Jetson Nano (PC2). He also has Wireshark installed and we weren't able to find anything meaningful there. We couldn't even seem to find packets going out from container 1 on his computer to container 2. Not sure if you have any ideas. I am at the point of trying to play around with Wireshark until I can see some packets from ROS, but I have zero experience.